# Bake and then Broil instead of flipping?

Tags: baking, oven, broiling

If I wanted to cook a meal - ie chicken wings - in a baking tray evenly on both sides, instead of turning them halfway through the cooking process, could I just switch from bake to broil midway so that both sides cook evenly? This is using a conventional oven with a heating ring on the top and bottom.

Comment: In my oven the broiler turns on the top heating coil and the bake setting turns on the bottom heating coil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for turning the food when baking is so the side that is in contact with the pan can get hit by the hot air. In the case of turning on the bake and then turning on the broil, you would still have the medium of what ever your food is sitting in.

If you are willing to elevated your food above a drip pan, turn on just the bottom heating coil (if possible), and set the food directly on the rack you could eliminate the need of turning halfway through the process.